# Eclipse maven project not recognising any of the dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, build-dependencies

I am trying to create maven project by importing as existing maven project from eclipse workspace project but eclipse is not able to resolve any of the dependencies. Everytime I create the project, update maven dependencies or clean project the dependencies get downloaded but they are not getting referenced from the local maven repository. The build is generated when i run `mvn clean install` from command line

I am exhausted trying out all the fixes for the issue like enabling indexing, cleaning the project, maven -> update project

My eclipse version is

```
 Eclipse version - Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
    Build id: 20190314-1200

Java version - java 11 openjdk
```

Maven preferences are like below

[image]

Also this is my maven setting when I run mvn - X

```
[DEBUG] Message styles: debug info warning error success failure strong mojo project
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /home/ramesh/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/share/maven/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /home/ramesh/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /home/ramesh/.m2/repository
```

Can someone help me understand the issue and fix ?

Comment: There should be more preferences under maven, you can unfold the menu item. Its been a long time ago but I remember that Eclipse bundles a Maven package and sets up its own local repository which you should be able to find in the additional preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below points to get solution from any.

1. Check if pom.xml is available in your project which you are
   importing.
2. Better to create your project with spring-initializr
   from https://start.spring.io/ and add all required dependencies.
3. At last, you can try to remove your .m2 directory available at home
   dir. and then again start eclipse and import project to re-install
   all jars.
4. You should use Maven -> Update and check forced update after import.

Hope you will find solution from any above point.